# Checking Last Time ASP.Net Form Was Updated

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have developed an ASP.NET web form with code behind in vb.net. I am wanting to check the last time that the form was update, by updating a label at the bottom of the form with a timestamp. What would be the best way to checking if the form was updated? I know I can go and check each button, text changed in the textboxes, etc. But that seems like a very long way to do it.... I didn't know if anyone had any experience doing this any other way?

Comment: What do you mean "last time it was updated"? Do you mean the last time the user modified the data in any form input? Do you want to have this happened on the client or server side?

Comment: Yes, anytime the user modifies text in textfields, makes choices in drop down list, clicks buttons. And Can be done client side, is what I was thinking

Comment: You'll need to attach a listener to each of the change events for the form elements. The listener should then call a JavaScript function where you can update a `<span>` with the last modified time. This will be easier with jQuery if you're open to using that.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking jQuery too. I think that's the route I will go.

Comment: I'd apply a class to each of the form elements you want to detect changes for, then use the `.classname` selector to reference them from jQuery.